# add to and change the environment in their own ways

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Dramatic play provides a risk-free stage where children can explore and experiment with ideas, test and evaluate their skills, and **add to** and change the environment in their own ways.

What's the meaning of "add to" here? They add which thing to the environment?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you provide a room for children to play in that has only a large cardboard box filled with wooden blocks.  The children could use the blocks to build pretend chairs, tables, people, dragons, and monsters.  They could use the box as a cave to hide with the wooden people from the monsters.  All these pretend objects and new uses would be things the children added to the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the shorter version of this sentence:

> Children can add to the environment in their own ways.

This says that children can add to the environment, but not exactly how. The same is true of the original sentence, it does not say how.